# AngularJS: traversing nested arrays

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working with a nested array with the structure...

```
$scope.items = [{attr1: val1, 
  attr2: val2,
  items: [{
     attr1: val1, 
     attr2: val2,
     items: [{
     ... 
     }, ...]
  }, ...]
}, ...];
```

which goes into an `ng-repeat` with `ng-include` like this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-include="'/path/to/template.tpl.html'"></div>
```

and `template.tpl.html` is

```
<div>{{item.attr1}}<\div>
<div>{{item.attr2}}<\div>
<div ng-click="fnAddNewItemBelow(item, $parent)"><\div>
<div ng-repeat="item in item.items" ng-include="'/path/to/template.tpl.html'"><\div>
```

Now, in the controller, I commonly want to do things like

- find an item's parent
- find an item's sibling
- make counts of siblings
- find out how many levels deep an item is nested
- insert or delete items at any level of the nest

But I'm not sure how to do this elegantly.  Eg imagine I wanted to implement `fnAddNewItemBelow`.  The two options I can work out are

### Traverse scopes

Use the nested scopes structure that Angular provides

```
// pseudo-code only
$scope.fnAddNewItemBelow = function (item, parent) {
  var newItem = ...;

  // add newItem as a sibling after the item that was ng-clicked
  // parent.$parent is necessary because the ng-include adds another scope layer (I think)
  parent.$parent.item.items.push(newItem);

  // (probably need to use .splice in case there are items after item, 
  //  but I'm keeping it simple)
}
```

But this is ugly because it assumes too much about the structure (what if I put an ng-if onto the `<div ng-click...`, which added another scope level... then I'd need `parent.$parent.$parent.item.items.push(newItem)`).

### Iterate nested array recursively until item.id is found

The alternative is to operate directly on `$scope.items`, since Angular will update UI and scopes associated with it. I can iterate recursively through `$scope.items` using for loops and after locating item by some unique id that it has, insert newItem after it

```
// pseudo-code only
$scope.fnAddNewItemBelow = function (item) {
  var newItem = ...;

  // add newItem as a sibling after the item that was ng-clicked
  fnSomeFunctionToFindItemAndInsertItemAfterIt(item.id, newItem);
}

fnSomeFunctionToFindItemAndInsertItemAfterIt (itemId, newItem) {
  // fancy recursive function that for loops through each item, and calls 
  // itself when there are children items. When it finds item with itemId, it 
  // splices in the newItem after
}
```

I don't like this because it requires iterating through the entire items tree every time I want to do something with the nested array.

Are there more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you alias `item.items` in the `ng-repeat` expression, angular will keep track of the array structure and hierarchical relationships for you.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items = item.items">
```

Then, operations on the tree can simply pass in the `item`, the `$index`, or the array of `items` - without knowledge of the full array structure:

```
  <button ng-click="addItem(item)">Add to my items</button>
  <button ng-click="addSiblingItem(items, $index)">Add a sibling item</button>
  <button ng-click="deleteMe(items, $index)">Delete Me</button>
```

js:

```
$scope.addItem = function(item) {
  item.items.push({
    attr1: 'my new - attr1',
    attr2: 'my new - attr2',
    items: []
  });
}
$scope.addSiblingItem = function(items, position) {
  items.splice(position + 1, 0, {
    attr1: 'sibling - new attr1',
    attr2: 'sibling - new attr2',
    items: []
  });
}
$scope.deleteMe = function(items, position) {
  items.splice(position, 1);
}
```

To get the number of siblings, you can refer to `items.length`:

```
<h3>Item #{{$index + 1}} of {{items.length}}</h3>
```

---

If you really need to access the parent siblings from child items, you can add another alias for `parent = item` and add it to the item using `ng-init`:

```
ng-repeat="item in items = (parent = item).items" ng-init="item.parent = parent"
```

Then you have access to the grandparent (`parent.parent`) and its `items` (the parent siblings).

In addition, you can keep track of the current nest level using `ng-init`:

```
ng-init="item.parent = parent; item.level = parent.level + 1"
```

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/xKSwHAUdXcGZcwHTDmiv

Comment: The `items` trick is great, and solves the "siblings" problems (add sibling, count siblings, delete sibling). Thanks!  And I had already solved the "children" problems the way you did. But I don't see how your solution helps with the "parent" problems. Eg how do I find parent, or find the nest level, or insert an item as, say, an "aunt"?  Did I miss something?

Comment: you could save off the parent with `ng-repeat="item in items = (parent = item).items"`.  then use `ng-init` to add the parent to the item: `ng-init="item.parent = parent"`.

Comment: Ha! This solution is as incredible and crazy as gorpacrate's solution. I'm going with this one for now because it's more convenient - Angular can manage the changes to the structure (moves of objects from one place to another, etc). Great work thanks! :)

Comment: If anyone's using this with an `ng-repeat` filter on the `items`, don't forget that `items` when passed into function calls is the PRE-filtered. I assumed the opposite => couple of hours of hurt

Comment: Plunker is no longer existing; which ng-repeat do you replace that with, there are two of them; is it the one in the template or the one before that and the template is no longer needed?

Comment: @CaptainFantastic the plunker link still works for me.  Maybe try forcing it to open in the legacy version?  http://plnkr.co/edit/xKSwHAUdXcGZcwHTDmiv?plnkr=legacy&p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Before rendering data, you can make some preparations. One recursive run over your data to set  level value and a link to the parent to each item.
Example with your data using LoDash:

```
var level = 0;
_.each($scope.items, function(item){recursive(item, level)});

function recursive(item, level){
    item.level = level;
    _.each(item.items, function(innerItem){
        innerItem.parent = item;
        recursive(innerItem, level+1);
    });
}
```

So now you can easily get parent and siblings of each item.

find an item's parent -> `item.parent`

find an item's sibling -> `item.parent.items[i]`

make counts of siblings -> `item.parent.items.length`

find out how many levels deep an item is nested -> `item.level`

insert or delete items at any level of the nest (move operation example) ->

```
newParent.items.push(item);
_.remove(item.parent.items, function(child){return child == item;});
```

The only minus of this approach which i met - you can not easily clone whole tree without going into endless recursion. But you can make custom cloning function which will not copy links.

Comment: This structure you created is beautiful... and frightening.  I had no idea you could do this without big recursion issues. Thanks for pointing out the one you found - I don't yet have a need to clone my structure. I will experiment with this in my project and see what other demons appear.

Comment: Good luck and write your thoughts! Using it almost for a year, seems ok.