# Angularjs - How to traverse, add and delete elements in nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a nested array:

```
$scope.audits = [{
    name: '2015', 
    sections:[{
    section:'mm',
    id:'1',
        subsections: [{
        subsection:'aa',
        mainelements: ['cc','dd']
        },{
        subsection:'bb',
        mainelements: ['ee','ff','gg']
        }]
    }]

}];
```

I want to have a few buttons to add and delete nested elements at will. I cannot use `$index` because it is multiple layers of array.

Here is my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NeumRxQzm2tIUvWUjnjc?p=preview)

Comment: you can add and delete elements with array.splice(), but you need an index.

Comment: to identify the right array you can use a second parameter at your remove function.

Comment: I just found out that I can use `$parent.$index` to get parent's index. I already updated my plunker

Answer (score 2):

This problem got it's crazy solutions out here: [AngularJS: traversing nested arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315679/angularjs-traversing-nested-arrays) . I'm not going to rewrite the solutions once again because it's unefficient. Don't forget to use search before asking a question.